# Firefox image 0px 0px scaled to actual size

Tags: firefox

I've nothing something strange in Firefox. I am using the current version of Firefox on Mac OS X but I think this can be reproduced on Windows machines, too.

I am embedding images on the website via the img tag using the alt, width and height attribute. The values fit the actual image size.

But:
When opening the page information and choosing media Firefox tells me the following:

Dimensions: 0px × 0px (Skaliert zu 500px × 400px)

why is this happen?

On some images Firefox shows "Dimensions: 450px × 294px"

Could you tell why Firefox is doing this? And is there a way to correct it, if necessary?